# the vue-awesome-swiper dependency was not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I tried to use swiper plugin on my nuxtjs project. But I've got error on my command line when I running "yarn run dev":
[image]
[image]
`

```
yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nuxt

 WARN  sass-loader@13.1.0 is installed but ^10.1.1 is expected


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

i Preparing project for development
i Initial build may take a while
√ Builder initialized
√ Nuxt files generated

* Client █████████████████████████ building (39%) 245/251 modul
es 6 active
 node_modules\setimmediate\setImmediate.js

× Server
  Compiled with some errors in 9.04s


× Client
  Compiled with some errors in 10.53s

× Server
  Compiled with some errors in 9.04s


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

This dependency was not found:

* vue-awesome-swiper/dist/ssr in ./plugins/swiper.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue-awesome-swiper/dist/ssr
i Waiting for file changes
i Memory usage: 143 MB (RSS: 232 MB)
i Listening on: http://localhost:3000/

 WARN  Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

`

vue-awesome-swiper does not detected while I've installed by "yarn add vue-awesome-swiper".

And I've followed this instruction on cmd:
npm install --save vue-awesome-swiper/dist/ssr
i Waiting for file changes
i Memory usage: 143 MB (RSS: 232 MB)
i Listening on: http://localhost:3000/

But still have issued on my code. Does anyone have same problems and had solution?

Comment: Hi, please try `{ src: '@/plugins/swiper.js', mode: 'client' }` rather.

Comment: Also, please do not mix npm and yarn. Keep one (I recommend yarn or PNPM).

Comment: thanks, have followed your instruction to use { src: '@/plugins/swiper.js', mode: 'client' }, then do "yarn add vue-awesome-swiper/dist/ssr" but still with the same issue.

Comment: Mind sharing the content of your plugin?